# SoapHttpClientProtocol receives unexpected content type

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mtom, wsdl.exe, soaphttpclientprotocol

I created a C# proxy class via `wsdl.exe` from a `WSDL`-URL. I'm using this proxy class in the context of a web app which I do not control (so there's no way to change a `web.conf` or similar). I'm also unable to change anything in the web service that I'm talking to.

When calling the web service, I receive the following exception:

```
Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; 
boundary="uuid:5c314128-0dc0-4cad-9b1a-dc4a3e5917bb"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; 
start-info="application/soap+xml"', but expected 'application/soap+xml'.
```

From what I've read, this is a problem with [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Transmission_Optimization_Mechanism) being used by the web service. Now I'm trying to tell my class to accept MTOM, but all I've found is configuration in the `web.conf`.

The proxy class is derived from `SoapHttpClientProtocol` and looks like this (relevant parts):

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]    
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "myrequestSoapBinding", Namespace = "http://namespace.of.company.of.webservice/")]
public class myrequest : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    public myrequest(string url)
    {
        this.SoapVersion = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap12;            
        this.Url = url;
    }

    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("return", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "base64Binary")]
    public byte[] getDocuments([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "base64Binary")] byte[] input)
    {
        try
        {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("getDocuments", new object[] {
                input});
            return ((byte[])(results[0]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var realResponse = StripResponse(ex.Message);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(realResponse.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The `try ... catch` in `getDocuments` is a hacky workaround that gets the 'real' service response out of the exception `Message` - which is not really how I want to implement this.

So my question is: Is there a way to change the binding in the proxy class to accept `MTOM` responses?

Answer (score 2):

From the small amount of research I've done in an effort to help, it appears that if you *did* have access to the web config (which I know you don't) and you turned on MTOM then Visual Studio would generate *two* proxy classes:

1. A standard one that derives from **SoapHttpClientProtocol**, and;
2. A WSE one with "Wse" appended to the class name that derives from **Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol**

It is the WebServicesClientProtocol implementation that is able to accept MTOM.  To have WSDL create a proxy that derives from WebServicesClientProtocol, follow the Note at the [top of this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529578.aspx).

Hopefully this will resolve the issue.